# I have 2 versions of Windows 7 on my boot menu, but only one works

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have 2 versions of Windows 7 on my boot menu, but only one works. How do I remove one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll use BCDEdit to edit the boot menu settings.  A good tutorial is [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2676-bcdedit-how-use.html).

Comment: bcdedit /delete {id}

Comment: You can make the change in windows, no need to drag another piece of software into the mix.

Comment: @Scott, BCDEdit is part of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) or the built-in BCDEdit, as Kevin mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

works with XP, start>run>msconfig>boot.ini>check all boot paths

Answer (score 0):

For XP it's:

Right click my computer -->
properties  -->
advanced  -->
startup and recovery  -->
settings

I'm pretty sure it's the same for Win7

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this myself.

Run msconfig, select the boot tab, and remove the unwanted entry.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is EasyBCD, like gharper mentions below, which has an easy to use GUI and more advanced functionality.

However, there is [a new beta version](http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=642) available that has improved Windows 7 support over the latest release.